# Problem generating typescript files from proto files

Tags: typescript, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am trying to generate typescript files based on several valid protofiles. The whole script work when generating other types of files - c#, java, etc... However, when trying to generate typescript files there is a problem.

First off, I have installed protoc globally and tried with both ts-protoc-gen and grpc-web_out.

I am executing the following code:

```
protoc --proto_path="path_to_dtos" --grpc-web_out=import_style=typescript,mode=grpcwebtext:"output_path" "file_path\file_name.proto"
```

This successfully executes and no error arise, however, no files are generated.

When trying to execute with ts-protoc-gen, I execute the following code:

```
protoc --proto_path="path_to_dtos" --plugin=protoc-gen-ts="path_to_plugin" --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:"output_path" --ts_out="output_path" "file_path\file_name.proto"
```

This gives an error: --ts_out: protoc-gen-ts: Access is denied.

I have tried putting it relative path, full path, no quotation marks, quotation marks, removing the --js_out from the latter, etc...

Here is how one of the proto files looks like:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package xxx.protobuf;

option java_package = "com.xxx.communication_types.dto";
option csharp_namespace = "xxx.DataCommunicationTypes";

message VersionDto {
    int32 major = 1; // Major version of the app 
    int32 minor = 2; // Minor version of the app
    int32 revision = 3; // Revision version of the app
}
```

I am at a total loss, I tried searching for some solutions but I couldn't find anything online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "quick" answer to this question, as manually compiling your DTOs from proto is not an wide practice. In most cases its something related to the paths that you use.

In your case, since the error is

> --ts_out: protoc-gen-ts: Access is denied.

I would assume its something related to protoc-gen-ts plugin

Try this

1. npm install  ts-protoc-gen -g 
   this would install the plugin globally this means that you can locate it in your AppFolder
2. Go to C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
   if you like to the module installed in this directory , that is your mistake, you need to link to the "compiled" version.
3. Link to C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\protoc-gen-ts.cmd